# Stop loading emacs configuration file setting a break point

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm rewriting my Emacs' .init file and I'd like to be able to stop loading it at some specific points.
It's like inserting a break point, but nothing to do with debugging.

I've tried using 'throw' and 'catch' but that's not really what I'm looking for.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can add `(debug)` at suitable places.  That will open a debugger window, where you can hit <kbd>c</kbd> to continue and <kbd>q</kbd> to quit.

Comment: Huh. I've been bisecting config files to debug all this time.  This seems much better.

Comment: You can also directly stop the initialization by `(signal 'quit nil)`. It barfs but you do not need to input `q` or `c` after that.

Comment: Now I have the feeling that I'm testing my init file the wrong way. Although (debug) and (signal) stops loading the file, they aren't very helpful as they clean the *Messages* buffer, which is where I look for information and errors. There must be a better way to test this.

Comment: Well I'm pretty certain that *nothing* deletes content from the `*Messages*` buffer. Certainly not by default -- to do so would be highly counter-productive. If you're not getting any messages, you're presumably calling the debugger before the messages would be generated?

Comment: I'll correct myself slightly -- `message-log-max` imposes a limit on the number of messages before the oldest ones are deleted. (But I'm guessing that's not relevant here.)