# Stop execution of .emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

Is there anyway to use a command in `.emacs` that tells Emacs to ignore anything that comes after it?

I am trying to isolate the source of problem in my `.emacs` file, and commenting in and out code is quite cumbersome.

Comment: Won't be super pretty, but couldn't you just put an `(error "Done")` at the point where you're bisecting?  You'll get the error that you signaled, and it won't get to the rest of the file.

Comment: @Dan, your solution worked best for me (no need to remember what I commented out, or where I left `)` of for `(quote ... )`. If you write it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Related answers in the comments of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24060841/stop-loading-emacs-configuration-file-setting-a-break-point/24061299#comment37102419_24061299.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put an `(error "Done")` in your `.emacs` file at the point where you're bisecting it.  You'll get the error that you signaled upon startup, but it will stop emacs from processing the rest of the `.emacs` file.

@Tom's suggestion about `comment-dwim` (and @Drew's comment about `comment-region`) are good ones, but the `(error "Done")` option has the advantage that you only need to move one line to various points in your `.emacs` file without commenting/uncommenting other bits of it -- which could get tedious and error-prone.

Answer (score 5):

Commenting and uncommenting is pretty easy if you use `M-;`, aka `comment-dwim`.  Just mark the region and type it -- it will comment or uncomment as appropriate.

Alternatively, sure, you can use the trick of wrapping the remainder of the file by putting `(quote` at the beginning and `)` at the end.  This will make the rest of the file appear as a constant, and it will just be discarded.

Comment: Even better than `comment-dwim` for commenting and uncommenting regions of text, IMO, is `comment-region`. It will nest already-commented code, instead of just uncommenting it. And with `C-u` it uncomments (one level of nesting). I bind `comment-region` to `C-x C-;`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just highlight half of the file and execute 'eval-region?